# Pasting to Excel from Word - stop a Word new line being converted into a new cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, copy-paste

So I have a table in MS Word which has two columns. In the second column the text is spread on multiple lines, ie I have pressed 'Enter' to achieve this.

When I paste into Excel, it converts these separate lines into separate cells.

What I want it to do is to keep the lines in the same cell, just on different lines, ie what would happen if I were to press Alt+Enter in a cell in excel.

How would I go about this?

**Edit:** here's an example of my data. In word it's in a word table.

```
----------------------------
| Bananas   | - yellow     |
|           | - curved     |
----------------------------
| Apples    | - red/green  |
|           | - round      |
----------------------------
```

Comment: in word how are the cells separated? also with [enter] ? or is it in a word-table?

Comment: It's a word table.

Answer (score 1):

Better answer:  [How do I copy Word tables into excel without splitting cells into multiple rows](https://superuser.com/questions/747197/how-do-i-copy-word-tables-into-excel-without-splitting-cells-into-multiple-rows)

The trick given is to copy/replace newline character in the Word table with something like the paragraph symbol ¶ (now I know that's also known as a "pilcrow").  You don't have to save the Word document to preserve your original.

Paste the modified data into Excel and then you can do another copy/paste to put the internal line breaks back inside the cells without splitting them.  The gimmick on the Excel side is using Alt-codes to define the search and replace.  See the referenced link.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting won't work. Alt+Enter in Excel isn't a special character, it's only a way of ensuring a CR+LF is stored within a cell rather than forcing you into the next cell.

One option would be to not press Enter in your Word table but use another character instead (e.g. '#') and then use a macro in Excel to search for '#' and replace with CHR(10) once you've pasted.